# Is is possible to find which IE user really has regardless of browser/document mode combinations?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-detection

Can I know which version of IE the user really has  no matter which browser/document mode combo he picked? I looked into parsing the user string (looking for "Trident" and "MSIE") and feature detection, but all of those seem to change based on browser/document mode selections. Is there something that is constant regardless of anything the user does by which I can detect the actual browser the user has?

Answer (score 0):

IE has a very specific list of user-agent tokens and here is a complete reference which includes its corresponding document mode:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#UATokenRef

In conjunction, a Trident token is added to the user-agent string when the compatibility mode is being set.

> This token includes a version number that enables you to identify the
>   version of the browser, regardless of the current browser mode.

Comment: That does not answer the question. the user-agent string actually changes if the user plays around with browser/document mode and there is no way to tell based on the user-agent string alone which IE the user actually has.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I had an incomplete answer and was not able to explicitly point it in inside the link. I've made the changes and I hope this answers your question